# Include more than one profile at top of event page

Tags: civievent, drupal, custom-fields, profile

I have a website with CMS Drupal 7.54 and CiviCRM version 4.7.16.

On the CiviCRM event configuration page under "online registration" tab, there are two fields available to include profiles (Include Profile(top of page) and Include Profile(bottom of page)). [image: profile]

I would like to add more than one profile using "Include Profile(top of page)", now its allowing to add only one profile at top of page. I noticed that there is an option to add another profile (bottom of page) but not on top of page.

If anyone knows solution for this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting two, and not just one bigger one?